# Square root series convergence or divergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$ converges or diverges using the direct comparison test.

Attempt:

$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}\Big(\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}} - 1\Big)$.

Then for positive $t$ we have $ 1 < \sqrt{1+t} < 1 + \frac{t}{2}$, because we have $(1 + \frac{t}{2})^{2} > 1 + t$.

Therefore we have $ 0 < \sqrt{n}\Big(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} - 1\Big) < \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$.

Now I know $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$ diverges. But I'm not sure I can claim the original series diverges since for the Direct comparison test to apply I have to show the original series is greater than a divergent series?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt {k+1} - \sqrt k = \sqrt {n+1} - 1$$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use that

$$ \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}} - 1\right) \sim \sqrt{n} \cdot\frac1{2n}=\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$

and then conclude by limit comparison test.

As an alternative we can use that

$$\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}} \ge 1+ \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2}$$

and conclude by direct comparison test.

Comment: I haven't covered the limit comparison test yet, so was wondering If i can conclude someway using direct comparison test or p-test. I think I'm nearly there except for the above issue.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner Take a look to it because it allows to solve many problem in a simpler way.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner I add an alternative by direct comparison test.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I keep seeing everyone posting this $ \sim$ sign. What does it means?

Comment: it means "asymptotically equivalent", take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).

Comment: okay so it means the ratio of their limits is 1. $\frac{\sqrt{n}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - 1\Big)}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n}} = 2n\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - 1\Big)$ then we somehow conclude this limit is $1$ for the asymptotic equivalence to hold?

Comment: @AnalysisLearner Intuitivelly they behaves in the same way therefore since one diverges also the other one diverges. The rigorous proof is given by [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: thanks, only issue I have is the limit comparison test they have the constraint that $ 0 < c < \infty$  where $c$ is the value of the limit. How can one conclude divergence, since that constraint means that the limit can never be infinity?

Comment: @AnalysisLearner The constant $c$ has nothing to do with the value of the series. The test simply states that when $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to c$ then the corresponding series both diverge or both converge. BTW we can also extend the test for the limit cases with $c=0$  for convergence) or $c=\infty$ (for divergence).

Comment: I'm not seeing how we utilise the limit comparison test here. We have that $\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n} \sim \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$. But what are we taking as our $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ to apply limit comparison test?

Comment: @AnalysisLearner We have $a_n=\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n} $ and $b_n=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$ then $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n}}{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}} \to \frac12$$

Comment: Thanks! Learning each day :D

Comment: @AnalysisLearner You are welcome! We are here for that I suppose. I always learn something each day. Bye

Answer (score 5):

Directly with a known test:

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt n}=\frac1{\sqrt2+1}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

and the last one is a sequence whose infinite series diverges as a scalar multiple of the divergent series $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\cfrac1{\sqrt n}\;$ ...and now use the comparison test for positive series.

**Another way:** observe that

$$S_k:=\sum_{n=1}^k(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\left(\sqrt2-\sqrt1\right)+\left(\sqrt3-\sqrt2\right)+\ldots+\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k\right)=$$

$$=\sqrt{k+1}-1\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\infty$$

and this means the sequence of partial sums of the series diverges to $\;\infty\;$ and thus so does the infinite series.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we have $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$
and the latter diverges, so the former does too.

*Added*:

I'll show why it two series $\sum_n a_n $ and $\sum_n b_n$ have asymptotically equivalent (ultimately) positive terms, and if 
one of them diverges, the other diverges too.

Indeed,suppose $\sum_n b_n$ diverges. By definition of equivalence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=1$, so for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N_0$ such that
\begin{align}
&&1-\varepsilon<\frac{a_n}{b_n}&<1+\varepsilon&&\text{ for all }\quad n\ge N_0\qquad \\
&\text{whence, as }\; b_n>0, &a_n&>(1-\varepsilon)b_n&&\text{ for all }\quad n\ge N_0,
\end{align}
which by the *comparison test*, implies that $\sum_n a_n$ diverges, just like the series $(1-\varepsilon)\sum_n b_n$.

Comment: why can we claim that the former diverges just because the latter does? What test is this using? As you see, I get to the same value of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ but I wasn't sure if/why I could claim divergence of the former...

Comment: @AnalysisLearner: I've added a proof of divergence. Is that clearer?